# Override abstract method behavior

Tags: php, class, inheritance, overriding, abstract

Hi it is possible to do something like this?

```
abstract class A {
    public function doSomething(){
        return 'Hi: ' . $this->changeMe();
    }
    abstract protected function changeMe();
}

class B extends A {
    protected function changeMe() {
        return 'B';
    }
}

class C extends A {
    protected function changeMe() {
        return 'C';
    }
}
```

doSomething on object B should return Hi: B, doSomething on object C should return Hi: C.

Comment: That's what it does for me.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/Y4WggW

Comment: Why don't you just try?